# How To Enable Menu in a Custom Theme in Android?

Tags: android, xml, themes, android-3.0-honeycomb

I'm creating an Android app using the theme "noTitlebar" and all the design changes are done and approved. Now I need to add a menu, so I have to add title bar. But, if I change the theme, the whole design for pop up, border, etc. will be affected.

So I created a custom theme by extending the theme
`"android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`.

I enabled the title by

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
```

Now I got the title bar, but menu is showing up. The control is not coming to

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
```

How can we enable menu in this theme? Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your are targeting Honeycomb (right?), when you say titlebar you probably mean [Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)? Follow the link to read the docs.

In a nutshell:

1. You need to set `targetSdkVersion="11"` and your build target (in eclipse) to v11.
2. Just use `Theme.Holo`. Action bar is by default enabled. `Theme.Holo` is a default theme for v11 so you even don't need to define it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Peter. I was able to find an almost equal theme, I can some some small UI tweaks and make it look alike. Also your answer helped me to find out the default theme.